# How realistic it is to combine money, fame, & be religious at the same for a Muslim?

Tags: hadith, jannah, world

Assalamu Alaikum,

In today's world, reconciling the pursuit of wealth, fame, and religious dedication is a common concern. Is it feasible to attain material success while upholding faith? Does seeking fame and fortune contradict religious values?

Islam encourages balanced ambitions. The desire for wealth and recognition is not inherently wrong, provided intentions remain pure and actions ethical. The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) highlighted the importance of sincere intentions.

Share your insights: How do I balance worldly goals with my faith?

Jazakum Allahu Khairan,

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Imam al-Laith ibn Sa'ad was a well known scholar of the 2nd hijri century he was a rich man who never had the duty to pay zakat sine even being rich all hsi welath was either investigated or given to the needy people.